# Can't get my counter correctly working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, operators, counter

This should be straightforward but I'm not getting it, most likely I've been looking at things far too long without a break but I could use another set of eyes on this. I trying to create a counter that tracks the number of photos taken `GameManager.CurrentStep` and then disables the photo button after it has reached the total number of photos needed `GameManager.instance.driftNumSteps`. For some reason there is an extra one at the end eg. if the total number of steps is 6 the camera doesn't disable and show `GameManager.instance.driftInstructionText.text = "Drift Completed!!";` until the seventh step.

```
    public void CapturePhoto(float latitude, float longitude)
    {
        // If all photos have been taken
        if (GameManager.CurrentStep <= GameManager.instance.driftNumSteps - 1)
        {
            // When a photo gets taken increment by 1
            GameManager.CurrentStep++;
            // Get the next drift step
            EventManager.GetDriftStep(GameManager.CurrentStep);
            // Insert photo data into SQL record
            GetComponent<SQLiteActions>().InsertPhotoData(GameManager.CurrentDriftID, "texture path", 78.33f, 87.1765f);

            /*if (PhoneCamera.backCam != null)
            {
                Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(PhoneCamera.backCam.width, PhoneCamera.backCam.height);
                photo.SetPixels(PhoneCamera.backCam.GetPixels());
                photo.Apply();

                SavePhotoToCameraRoll(photo);       // Save photo to camera roll gallery
                //SavePhotoToLocalStorage(photo);   // Save photo to local app storage

                Debug.Log("Photo Captured!");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Phone Camera Not Found!");
            }*/
        }
        else
        {
            // Tell user their drift is done!
            GameManager.instance.driftInstructionText.text = "Drift Completed!!";
            // Fade camera button maybe?
            Debug.Log("Drift is complete!!");
            UIActions.EnableButton(GameManager.instance.newDriftBtn); // Enable create new drift button
            UIActions.DisableButton(GameManager.instance.takePhotoBtn); // Disable photo button button
        }

        Debug.Log(GameManager.CurrentStep + " out of " + GameManager.instance.driftNumSteps + " steps.");
    }
```

Comment: The code appears to do what you describe assuming CurrentStep is initialized to 0.  Put another way if driftNumSteps == 6, and CurrentStep is only incremented in the above function, then CurrentStep should never become greater than 6.  While 0..6 is a range of 7, GetDriftStep (in the function) should only be called 6 times (range 1..6).   I know that probably doesn't help but at least now set_of_eyes++

Comment: What is the very first output from `Debug.Log(GameManager.CurrentStep + " out of " + GameManager.instance.driftNumSteps + " steps.");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback! I solved the problem. I was retrieving from a List at 1 rather than zero. Once I adjusted my return to return GameManager.Drift[currentStep - 1].DriftStep; everything worked fine.